# Flip Image with react-konva

Tags: reactjs, image, flip, konvajs, react-konva

With https://github.com/lavrton/react-konva

How can I flip an image (horizontally or vertically)
I am using this function, but it is not working:

```
  flip = direction => {
    this.setState({
      width: -this.state.width
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to use scale property:

```
<Image image={this.state.image} scaleY={-1} y={200}/>
```

So in your state, you should store `scale` property with 1 or -1 values,

https://codesandbox.io/s/v6yk2j2w0l

Comment: It works great but it creates a shift: https://j.gifs.com/OyjMkr.gif. All image manipulation shouldn’t shift the viewport. is there a way to do it?

Comment: @Alan You just need to adjust `x` property or set `offsetX={imageWidth / 2}`